# Programmatically trigger a @Scheduled method?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I'm working on a Springboot app that includes a task that's executed on a schedule. It typically takes about two to three minutes to run.

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "* */30 * * * *")
public void stageOfferUpdates() throws SQLException {
    ...
}
```

We have a requirement to be able to kick off the execution of that task at any time by calling a rest endpoint. Is there a way my `@GET` method can programmatically kick this off and immediately return an `http 200 OK`?

Comment: Simply call the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to trigger an async task without waiting for results. Because you are using Spring, [the `@Async` annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) is an easy way to achieve the goal.

```java
@Async
public void asyncTask() {
    stageOfferUpdates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just run the method in another Thread:

```
executor.execute(() -> {
    stageOfferUpdates();
}
```

and then procede and return 200?

Comment: That's kinda my question...is that the correct way to do it? Or is there something in Spring that's considered preferred? I've googled this but didn't find anything particularly helpful. Anyway, that's probably what I'll do.

Thanks!

Comment: Well you got your answer i guess :)